# How to use multithreading in a loop in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, runnable, callable

Here's what I'm trying to do. I am recording data from different sensors in a `while loop` until the user stops the recording. I want to record as much data as possible per second. The sensors require different time to return a value, between 200ms and 3 seconds. Therefore, sequentially calling the sensors successively is not an option.

Sequentially calling the sensors looks like this:

```
List<DataRow> dataRows= new ArrayList<DataRow>();

while (recording) {
   DataRow dataRow = new DataRow();

   dataRow.setDataA(sensorA.readData());
   dataRow.setDataB(sensorB.readData());
   dataRow.setDataC(sensorC.readData());

   dataRows.add(dataRow);
}
```

Depending on the sensor, reading the data looks (much simplified) like that

```
public class SensorA {

   public SensorAData readData(){
      sensorA.startSensing();

      try {
          TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(750);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
      }

      return sensorA.readAndConvertByteStream();
   }
}
```

To utilize Multithreading can SensorA implement `Callable` and receive `Future` objects in the loop? Or should the `while loop` be placed within a `run()` method implementing the interface `Runnable`?

Basically, can Java (or a thread) write to the correct `dataRow` object even if the loop is already at least one iteration further? If not, how can one solve this problem?

Comment: You could use a thread-safe `Collection` from the `java.util.concurrent` package and pass it to all sensor threads. The sensor threads get allocated from a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. The main thread would do nothing, just `wait()` on an object or `Thread.sleep()` repeatedly, until an `InterruptedException` is thrown, at which point you shut down the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: Re: `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` if you are just going to exit I think it's acceptable to not set the interrupt bit.  You only need to set that if some other part of the code needs to detect the interrupt bit and therefore exit.  This means that `readAndConvertBytes` might exit early if it sees the interrupt bit.  Probably not what you want.

Comment: `can Java (or a thread) write to the correct dataRow object` That's going to depend a lot on details that you haven't show us.  Read/write loops have to be thread safe, and we can't tell if these are.  If the objects are NOT SHARED with any other thread, then it's probably ok (but watch out for objects that share global state underneath the hood).

Comment: IMO you need to think harder about your requirements.  It's easy to write one loop that polls sensor A five times per second and, a different loop that polls sensor B once every three seconds and, to run those loops in different threads.  That's pretty close to what threads were invented for in the first place.  But, I can't tell from reading your question what it is that you want to _do_ with those two streams of data that are coming in at very different speeds.  How many data rows do you want to output per second?  Which data do you want to see in which row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your needs correctly, this may be solution you want:

- In each iteration n sensors are read by n concurrent threads,
- If all threads has sensors data collected, new result row is added to list

**Working code:**

```
public class TestX {

    private final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    private final int N = 10;

    // all sensors are read sequentially and put in one row
    public void testSequential() {
        int total = 0;
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.println("starting iteration " + i);

            int v1 = getSensorA();    // run in main thread
            int v2 = getSensorB();    // run in main thread
            int v3 = getSensorC();    // run in main thread

            // collection.add( record(v1, v2, v3)
            total += v1 + v2 + v3;
        }

        System.out.println("total = " + total + "   time = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t) + " ms");
    }

    // all sensors are read concurrently and then put in one row
    public void testParallel() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        int total = 0;
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();

        final SensorCallable s1 = new SensorCallable(1);
        final SensorCallable s2 = new SensorCallable(3);
        final SensorCallable s3 = new SensorCallable(3);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.println("starting iteration " + i);

            Future<Integer> future1 = pool.submit(s1);  // run in thread 1
            Future<Integer> future2 = pool.submit(s2);  // run in thread 2
            Future<Integer> future3 = pool.submit(s3);  // run in thread 3

            int v1 = future1.get();
            int v2 = future2.get();
            int v3 = future3.get();

            // collection.add( record(v1, v2, v3)
            total += v1 + v2 + v3;
        }

        System.out.println("total = " + total + "   time = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t) + " ms");
    }

    private class SensorCallable implements Callable<Integer> {

        private final int sensorId;

        private SensorCallable(int sensorId) {
            this.sensorId = sensorId;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            switch (sensorId) {
                case 1: return getSensorA();
                case 2: return getSensorB();
                case 3: return getSensorC();
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown sensor id: " + sensorId);
            }
        }
    }

    private int getSensorA() {
        sleep(700);
        return 1;
    }

    private int getSensorB() {
        sleep(500);
        return 2;
    }

    private int getSensorC() {
        sleep(900);
        return 2;
    }

    private void sleep(long ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // ignore
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        new TestX().testSequential();
        new TestX().testParallel();
    }
}
```

**and output:**

```
starting iteration 0
starting iteration 1
starting iteration 2
starting iteration 3
starting iteration 4
starting iteration 5
starting iteration 6
starting iteration 7
starting iteration 8
starting iteration 9
total = 50   time = 21014 ms

starting iteration 0
starting iteration 1
starting iteration 2
starting iteration 3
starting iteration 4
starting iteration 5
starting iteration 6
starting iteration 7
starting iteration 8
starting iteration 9
total = 50   time = 9009 ms
```

-- EDIT --

in java 8 you can use method reference to get rid of Callable classes and just write:

```
Future<Integer> future1 = pool.submit( this::getSensorA() );
Future<Integer> future2 = pool.submit( this::getSensorB() );
Future<Integer> future3 = pool.submit( this::getSensorC() );
```

Comment: Thank you @przemek-hertel for your elaborate proposition. As far as I understand `future.get()` will wait for a result and effectively pause the loop until the slowest sensor is ready. Is there a way to continue the loop and write the data of the slow sensor as soon as it is ready?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You may use producer-consumer pattern with BlockingQueue. 
Your loop is the producer (main thread) and puts request objects to queue. You have to start pool of consumer threads that get requests from queue, read sensor (described in request) and finally put the result to result collection.